# high mp3 quality->low conversion using PHP

Tags: php, audio, mp3

How to convert 320 kbps mp3 file into e.g. 32 kbps one using PHP?

Comment: 320 kbps is also low quality but 32kbps? if you are on a managed server, you cant use exec normally. you need a root server with root access

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could call some command-line MP3-related program that would do the conversion.

The result would probably be better than using a purely-php-based library<sup>1</sup>.

For example, [**lame**](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) might be useful, here.

Then, from your PHP code, to run that external program, you'll nee to use one of the [**Program execution Functions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php), like [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

<sup>1.</sup> <sub>If there is even such a thing</sub>